# Copy files from external storage into internal storage in Android 11

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-11, scoped-storage

I want to use some .pdf files in my app which are located in external storage. For using those files in android 10&11 I am going to copy files into internal storage. My code is working well in Android 10 but not in Android 11

```
Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

error is coming.

My code is as below;

manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.packagename"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
<files-path
    name="."
    path="/"/>
</paths>
```

in fragment

```
val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                "com.packagename",
              File("/sdcard/Documents/PDFConverter/my_file.pdf")
            )

ScopeStoreUtils.copyFileIntoFiles(context, contentUri)
```

util class

```
object ScopeStoreUtils {

fun copyFileIntoFilesDir(context: Context, fileUri: Uri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        // r for read
        try {
            val parcelFileDescriptor = 
            context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "r", null)
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor)
            val destinationFile = File(context.filesDir, 
            context.contentResolver.getFileName(fileUri))
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(destinationFile)
            copy(inputStream, outputStream)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ScopeStoreUtils", "copyFileIntoFilesDir: Exception: $e")
        }
    }
}



private fun ContentResolver.getFileName(fileUri: Uri): String {
    var name = ""
    val returnCursor = this.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)
    if (returnCursor != null) {
        val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
        returnCursor.close()
    }
    return name
}


@Throws(IOException::class)
fun copy(input: InputStream?, output: OutputStream?): Int {
    val count = copyLarge(input!!, output!!)
    return if (count > Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        -1
    } else count.toInt()
}


private const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4


@Throws(IOException::class)
fun copyLarge(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream): Long {
    val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    var count: Long = 0
    var n: Int
    while (-1 != input.read(buffer).also { n = it }) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n)
        count += n.toLong()
    }
    return count
}


}
```

Comment: `FileProvider` is for sharing content with other apps. It does not give you any permissions that you presently lack. A simple `FileInputStream` on the file is simpler and gives the same results. Note that Kotlin has a `copyTo()` extension function on `InputStream` that is a simpler choice for copying between streams than is the code that you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I have tried to use copyTo() extension function as   * val path = "/sdcard/Documents/PDF Converter/IMG_20210602_175043_pdf.pdf"
* val sourceFile = File(path)
* sourceFile.copyTo(it.filesDir, true) ->> result is "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Documents/PDF Converter/IMG_20210602_175043_pdf.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" which I am suffered for hours @CommonsWare

Comment: That is because you do not have access to that file. `FileProvider` does not help with that. Make sure that you have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on the `<application>` element in your manifest, to cover Android 10.

Comment: I have no problem in android 10, problem is in Android 11. Moreover Google warns for using android:requestLegacyExternalStorage since last month. Thats why I am removing android:requestLegacyExternalStorage from manifest file.

Comment: "problem is in Android 11" -- then you may not have read access to `Documents/` for files that you did not create. You may need to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to choose the PDF to copy. You can use the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` to read from.